# Built a electret preamp but poor low frequency response

Tags: preamp, electret

I have built this preamp using the TL071 IC. 
[image: Circuit schematic]

It works, but it does have a bad low frequency response. If I plug the mic directly to my PC i can hear low frequencies much better. I don't have any software equalizers active on my PC.
What is the problem? Also, is this design good?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So let's analyze the low frequency cutoff:

At the input we have a high-pass filter made by C2, R2 and R3. For the audio signal R2 and R3 are in parallel so they are combined 50 k Ohm.

The cutcoff frequency is at

\$f_c = \frac 1 {2\pi RC} \$

For C = 0.1 uF and R = 50 k ohm that gives \$f_c\$ = 32 Hz

That's a bit high, I suggest that you replace C2 with a 1 uF capacitor which will lower \$f_c\$ to 3.2 Hz, that's low enough.

At the output something similar can happen **depending on what you connect to the output**. If you would connect to an input with 50 kohm input resistance then again you would get a cutoff point at 32 Hz.

However, most line inputs have a much lower input resistance though, in the order of 10 kohm. That will move the cutoff point to a much higher frequency and you will definitely hear that, the 32 Hz at the input is still " OK-ish" but much higher than that and sound will suffer (as you have experienced).

Again I suggest increasing the capacitor's value. I would make C4 10 uF, yes that's 100 times larger than you have now!

Answer (score 2):

- C2, R2 and R3 have a cut-off of 31.8 Hz
- C5 and R5 are OK at about 3.9 Hz

But the killer might be your input impedance that connects to A_OUT2. If it is (say) 10 kohm then the cut-off due to C4 and the unknown impedance (assumed to be 10 kohm) is 159 Hz and will get worse such that if the input impedance is 1 kohm then the cut-off will be 1.6 kHz. Try upping C4 to 10 uF and see what happens.

> Also, is this design good?

The TL071 op-amp isn't recommended at supplies lower than 10 volts - you have 9 volts and that will fall with battery life. Choose a more appropriate op-amp.

Comment: Where do you read that 10V thing in the datasheets?

Comment: @PlasmaHH In recommended operating conditions before the main tables on performance. It states +/- 5 volts.

Comment: Ah, looks like I was looking at the ST micro datasheet and you at the TI ...